# Error attempting to read GeoJSON file in Flask Application

Tags: geojson, geometry, geopandas, mapbox, flask

I have a Flask Application in which I am rendering scatter and choropleth maps using MapBox.

For choropleth map, I need the census geometries. This is a fairly large GeoJSON file ~150mb. When I attempt to read this file in my application code and launch the app locally, it times out. This file takes a few minutes to load even in Jupyter Notebook.

I am wondering if there are any workarounds to this. How do I read this file more efficiently?

I have tried a few different ways to read the file, but none of them worked.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import geojson

# Read census geometry from S3
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='data', Key='uscensusgeo.geojson')
df_geo = gpd.read_file(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))

df_geo = pd.read_json(os.getcwd() + "/data/uscensusgeo.geojson")

df_geo = gpd.read_file(os.getcwd() + "/data/uscensusgeo.geojson")

print(df_geo.head())
```

The application times out when I include the code to read `geojson` data. It doesn't throw an error. When I remove the code and any references to the `geojson` data, the application works fine.

Comment: Either switch to a more efficient format, or load the features a few at a time

Comment: @IanTurton could you comment on a more efficient format to read the data in?

Comment: Well a zipped json file, or almost any binary file will be smaller and quicker to read

Comment: Do you need to have the Census input data in the GeoJSON format? Because if you don't, I'd *highly* recommend just using another file format entirely. My personal preference is to use GeoPackage (gpkg), which works really well with GeoPandas. Is that option on the table for you, or does the Census data *absolutely need*  to be in GeoJSON?